# Read time out issue on 3 Tier java web application

Tags: java, timeout

Our web application's structure is 3 Tier. (Presentation layer, Business layer, DB layer)
All business logic is in the business layer.
Presentation layer requests CRUD to business layer and get result to process users' request.
By the way, we configured read time out on presentation layer. (3 secounds)
In this case, if some results slowly come from business layer, user get error message and the CRUD processing is correctly finished. So user try action again. As a result, data is duplicated.
How to solve this problem? Just increase read time out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long running transactions in the business layer, you should implement a COMET like mechanism on the Presentation Layer:

1. User submit transaction, business layer returns immediately
2. Transaction executes in the background in the business layer
3. Presentation Layer regularly polls the business layer to check the state of the transaction

Unfortunately, this mechanism usually requires some significant implementation changes in both the Presentation and Business Layer. On the client side, javascript frameworks provide these kind of features out of the box. On the server side, Asynchronous Servlets found in servlet 3.0 may help.

Increasing read timeouts alone is simple but will not get you out of this in most cases: if the clients requests go through proxies/firewalls etc..., the latter will likely timeout and close connections before your Presentation Layer does.

Comment: Websockets is an interesting alternative to polling, comet, and such.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau very true. [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is an interesting library providing websockets where it can and traditional polling techniques as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a rollback and do that if you reach the timeout, or rather just commit the database transaction if you finish before the timeout. Increasing the timeout doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

The best option really is to have the client receive ack of the request and then (later) a confirmation of completion or failure.  This covers typical scenarios except loss of contact or a really slow job.

Increasing your timeout is sensible a 3 second timeout is not practical for most serious work (what if the server is temporarily busy or you have a network delay?).